# Send Integration Keys with Secret Keys after login in docusign

Tags: docusignapi, docusignconnect

I'm trying to access DocuSign account and app.
How to pass to docusign login without client_id, once login successful it will ask for app and send Integration Keys with Secret Keys of that app in callback?

Step1- User redirect to DocuSign login page with url somethings like this
Response.Redirect(WebUtilities.AddQueryString(Options.AuthorizationEndpoint, new Dictionary<string, string>{
{ "scope", "signature extended" },
{ "response_type", "code" },
{ "state", stateString },
{ "redirect_uri", Options.AppUrl + Options.CallbackPath.ToString() }                            })
);

and after successful login.

Step2. User should have screen with apps which are in setting and from there after selected any app, it will send Integration key/ Secret key of selected app to call back url. By which I want make calls are per my requirements.

Basic point is user from my web site click on docsign link- it will redirect to login of DocuSign - user will select app on successful login - select app which user want - After selection it will redirect to callback with with IntegrationKey and Secret key.

Hope I am clear now.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately your question is not clear. Maybe you can edit it.

To `make` an API call `to` DocuSign, you need an access_token. Your application obtains an access_token by using an OAuth authentication flow such as Authorization Code grant or JWT grant.

To `receive` a webhook notification `from` DocuSign, you set up your Connect/webhook subscription by using the eSignature Administration tool. You do not need a client_id for this action.

### Added

The OP has added to their question:

> Basic point is user from my web site click on docsign link- it will redirect to login of DocuSign - user will select app on successful login - select app which user want - After selection it will redirect to callback with with IntegrationKey and Secret key.

I think the question is about authenticating an application's user with DocuSign, then returning to the application.

#### Answer

The OAuth security standards for the Authorization Code grant require that the user login via the OAuth service provider. In this case account.docusign.com or account-d.docusign.com.

There are two ways to do this:

- The application `redirects` the user's browser to the OAuth service provider. After the first step in the Authorization Code grant flow, the user will be redirected back to the application. The application then makes the call to exchange the authorization code for an access token. The app needs a way to recover its state when the user is redirected back to it. There are several ways to do this.
- The application can open a new browser tab to the OAuth service provider. The application continues to run in its original browser tab. The app can programmatically close the tab that it created once the user is authenticated.

Once your app has an access token for DocuSign, it can make API calls to DocuSign. Generally speaking, apps should make API calls to DocuSign on behalf of the user. It is less common for apps to show the DocuSign application to users.

The exception is the DocuSign Signing Ceremony, used for actually signing a document. But signers rarely have a login to DocuSign--they don't need a login to sign.

If you're going to show the DocuSign signing ceremony to your application's users then your application will usually obtain an access token for a system user such as "finance@example.com" (via OAuth JWT impersonation grant) not for the signer since the signer does not have a DocuSign login.